Is there a statistical test where you test whether any of multiple separate analyses of variances or chi-square tests are statistically significant?
Is there a statistical test where you test whether any of multiple separate analyses of variances or chi-square tests are statistically significant?

Look into multiple comparisons, search this site!

Levene test will test whether >=2 variances are equal
Levene test, wikipedia
H. Levene (1960). Contributions to Probability and Statistics. Stanford University Press, CA.
M. B. Brown and A. B. Forsythe (1974). "Robust tests for the equality of variance," Journal of the American Statistical Association, 69, 364-367.
